# When to use row column in Zurb Foundation 6.2.3?

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

When do yo use row column construct in Zurb Foundation 6.2.3 framework?

```
<div class="column row">
  Row column
</div>
```

It almost identical to,

```
<div class="row">
    Row
</div>
```

Only that row column is shorter in length.

Comment: It's in the documentation: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#combined-column-row

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the way framework grids work (not only foundation), `.row` elements are not meant to be content containers itself, `.column` are. Grid elements has paddings and margins and, if you use just `.row`, that would cause misalignment with other elements on the grid. So, if you have something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column medium-6">Column A</div>
    <div class="column medium-6">Column B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">Column C, full width always</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column medium-6">Column D</div>
    <div class="column medium-6">Column E</div>
</div>
```

Please take a look to the **Column C**, as it is full width on all breakpoints, doesn't need to have sizing classes, so just "column" or "columns" will suffice, but it still having an extra div with no other need than having the proper sizing/padding/margin to keep content alignment to upper and lower row, so... it's better if second row is: `<div class="row column">Column C, full width always</div>`, just that.

That's the situation in which you should use the *row column* construct; and yes, I do encourage you to use that construct, avoid use `.row` as direct content container.

Hope this helps.